# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String' webservice call

Tags: arrays, vb.net, web-services, arraylist

Hey all I am getting the error of:

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'.

On this line of my code:

```
Dim blah As String = webService.theQ(qString:="SELECT blah FROM table WHERE blah = 'hello'")
```

My web service **sqlQ** function code is:

```
<WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
Public Function theQ(ByVal qString As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim results As Object = fetchSQLQ("query", qString(0))
    ...etc etc
    Dim ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(results)

    return strResponse
End Function
```

I'm not sure how to format it like its calling for?

This is how I go about calling it using AJAX (and it works fine):

```
var sqlCC = "SELECT blah FROM table WHERE blah = 'hello'";

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "/Service1.asmx/theQ",
    data : JSON.stringify({
        qString : [sqlCC]
    }),
    success : function (data2) {
        var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data2);
    },
    error : function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: qString has type List(Of String) but you pass it only a string ; theQ is a `Sub` which produce no return value but you use it as a `Function`

Comment: @Sehnsucht check my OP for more of the web service code to explain better what I am returning.

Comment: @StealthRT Please see my answer - it explains what you do wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is **parameter** that you're passing to your webs service. You pass

```
webService.theQ(qString:="SELECT blah FROM table WHERE blah = 'hello'")
```

Where you assigning string to `qString`. But in your declaration

```
Public Sub theQ(ByVal qString As List(Of String))
```

`qString` is declared as list of strings.

And also, your web methos is a `SUB` which doesn't have any return value, therefore

```
Dim blah As List(Of String) = webService.theQ(. . . .
```

is not even legal

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much says it all. The webservice call is returning a string, not a list of strings. If you look at your script code, it parses the result of the AJAX call as JSON. While I can't tell for sure from the rest of your code, it is quite possible that the webservice call is returning a JSON string as well.

Easy way to confirm:

```
Dim blah as String = webService.theQ(...)
' Print out the value of blah or inspect in debugger...
```

If the string is JSON, then you'll have to parse it to get the list you seek.

Comment: Using **Dim blah As String** still has the same error.